# Quickbooks Free Edition 2010 - How do I subtract vacation or sick time available to an employee?

Tags: quickbooks

I'm not sure if this is possible in QB 2010 simple start (I have payroll hooked up to it).

However, when I print a pay stub it shows the accrued vacation & sick time.  One of my employees took some sick time, so I'd like it to show 1 less day of sick time.

Is there a way to fix this or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you paid the employee sick time, did you use the regular Wage item or the Sick Hourly/Sick Salary item?  Make sure to use the Sick item, and it will deduct it from their accrued sick time.

Comment: Thanks Theo - I did the regular. I will need to go back and fix this. Much appreciated.